How to attach eventhandler to DataGrid Combobox Selection Changed
Using the DataGrid in the Community ToolKit. How can one bind an eventhandler to listen for a change in the DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Unfortunately, you can't. One way to achieve this is to use the DataGridTemplateColumn with a CheckBox in it.
For example:
*.xaml
<toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="IsEnabled">
        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox
                    Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"
                    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>

then in code-behind you'll have:
*.xaml.cs
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        return;
    }

    comboBox.ItemsSource = ComboBoxItems;
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Selected item: {e.AddedItems.ToString()}");
}

UPDATE
You can also create a custom DataGridComboBoxColumn:
public class DataGridComboBoxColumnEx : DataGridComboBoxColumn
{
    public event SelectionChangedEventHandler? SelectionChanged;

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox)base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
        
        comboBox.SelectionChanged -= ComboBox_SelectionChanged;
        comboBox.SelectionChanged += ComboBox_SelectionChanged;
        return comboBox;
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}

Then use it like a plain DataGridComboBoxColumn:
<local:DataGridComboBoxColumnEx
    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboBoxItems}"
    Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Header="Enabled" />


I tried this, but I can't seem to get my itemSource binding to work(since this is a comboBox. I My combobox column simply had a itemSource={x:Bind} binding directly to a property in code behind(that is not the same as the datagrid data context. With datatemplate, this doesn't seem to work?

Sorry about that. I updated my answer with a ComboBox.

Where is the source for the ComboBox? On each item? code-behind?

it is basically a object that is defined in the codebehind that has a property that is a list of another property.  With x:bind in dataGridComboBoxColumn I could just use {x:Bind propertyInCodeBehind.List and then define DisplayMemberPath to the String.

I updated my answer. I hope it helps.

I updated my answer again with another option. I hope you like it.
